# Help me fix play in Gossamer cranks

Tags: maintenance, repair, crankset

I just bought a used bike for cheap. The crank/pedals feel loose and wiggle a bit from side. I notice there's a hole straight through the crank where I feel like some part is missing, perhaps some sort of bolt? (See pictures.)

Can someone help me diagnose the problem and tell me how to remove the play in the cranks, any potential replacement parts etc.? The crank model name is: FSA Gossamer 52-42-30 Mega, and the bike is Merida Speeder T3. size: 55,5cm.

[image: Left side]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are the cranks wiggling on the bottom-bracket axle?  Or is the entire BB axle wiggling inside the frame ?

Comment: Nathans suggestion worked but I noticed it is still a little bit loose. I think the whole axle is loose inside the frame

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nothing is missing. To adjust these you loosen the pinch bolts on the left crank with a 5mm wrench, use the same 5mm wrench to gently tighten down the large black preload adjusting bolt that's found on the outside of the left crank, and then re-torque the pinch bolts.

This bike appears to be in pretty rusty/unkempt shape. It would be a good idea to at minimum remove and clean/grease the preload bolt because it's aluminum and has a lot of fine threads and they can corrode and/or get sticky and disrupt your torque feel.

Some amount of loosening of this kind of bottom bracket is normal and easy to adjust out. There are many questions here on this. The style you have adjusts exactly the same way as the more common Shimano cranks, which is the sort that will more often be mentioned by name in questions. It's also common for lower-end FSA external bottom brackets like this to be worn out, because they're mediocre quality. You can replace the one you have with a Shimano road BB, which are cheaper and better than their FSA counterparts.

Comment: Oops, if I had managed to notice you had answered, I might have left the question alone but I don't think I have undermined your answer with my edit...

Comment: I'd deep clean the bike and check over everything for further problems

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot Nathan